# Cleaning disabled SQL agent jobs in SQL Server 2005 and above

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

For many of our old servers, we have found that there are lot of SQL agent jobs which were either run as an ad-hoc for instant purpose and now no more needed OR Jobs which are not functional/working and replaced by some new jobs, are just sitting idle and occupying the unwanted attention on the job activity list:

Hence, I would like to know, should we be good to clean up all those disabled jobs?
(I am not sure if they are sitting idle there, what would be current or future impact)

If yes, what should be the safest way of cleaning them in one go, for cases where there is quite a big list of disabled jobs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only you can answer if the jobs can be dropped completely. If they are not jobs like from the import/export wizard I would probably script them out. This can be done easily with PowerShell.

A quick way of dropping them is via Object Explorer details pane, it allows multiple selections and then just hit the delete key or right click and delete.

Comment: Object Explorer Details will allow you to right-click and script, too. So, you know, if you don't know PowerShell, you don't have to go learn it to save yourself a right-click. :-)

Comment: True that, just habit.